# Drag and drop that works with touch and mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, drag, drop

I followed this [guide](https://www.horuskol.net/blog/2020-08-15/drag-and-drop-elements-on-touch-devices/) and I tried implementing the code myself, but when I run it I get a "move is not defined" error. Any suggestions on what I did wrong? Tried moving the script reference around or not including the event listeners in the html tag which would constrain the movement to only inside the container, but nothing seems to change? Any suggestions? Thanks!

```js
let moving = null;


function pickup(event) {
    moving = event.target;

    moving.style.height = moving.clientHeight;
    moving.style.width = moving.clientWidth;
    moving.style.position = 'fixed';
    moving.style.zIndex = '-10';
}

function move(event) {
    if (moving) {
        if (event.clientX) {
            // mousemove
            moving.style.left = event.clientX - moving.clientWidth/2;
            moving.style.top = event.clientY - moving.clientHeight/2;
        } else {
            // touchmove - assuming a single touchpoint
            moving.style.left = event.changedTouches[0].clientX - moving.clientWidth/2;
            moving.style.top = event.changedTouches[0].clientY - moving.clientHeight/2;
        }
    }
}

function drop(event) {
    if (moving) {
        if (event.currentTarget.tagName !== 'HTML') {
            let target = null;
            if (event.clientX) {
                target = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
            } else {
                target = document.elementFromPoint(event.changedTouches[0].clientX, event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
            }

            target.appendChild(moving);
        }

        // reset our element
        moving.style.left = '';
        moving.style.top = '';
        moving.style.height = '';
        moving.style.width = '';
        moving.style.position = '';
        moving.style.zIndex = '';

        moving = null;
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #container > div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
  
    height: 10em;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  #movable-element {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: #00ff0033;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<html onmouseup="drop(event)" ontouchend="drop(event)" onmousemove="move(event)" ontouchmove="move(event)">
<head>
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left-parent" onmouseup="drop(event)" ontouchend="drop(event)">
        <div id="movable-element" onmousedown="pickup(event)" ontouchstart="pickup(event)"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-parent" onmouseup="drop(event)" ontouchend="drop(event)"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the "move is not defined" is because you're setting the move event listener on the HTML tag, which is before you defined the "move" function.

The solution is to move the event listeners to the body tag, which is after the move function is defined.

There are other issues with this code, but that addresses the one issue in your question. If you need further help with the other issues please post a new question.

```js
let moving = null;


function pickup(event) {
    moving = event.target;

    moving.style.height = moving.clientHeight;
    moving.style.width = moving.clientWidth;
    moving.style.position = 'fixed';
    moving.style.zIndex = '-10';
}

function move(event) {
    if (moving) {
        if (event.clientX) {
            // mousemove
            moving.style.left = event.clientX - moving.clientWidth/2;
            moving.style.top = event.clientY - moving.clientHeight/2;
        } else {
            // touchmove - assuming a single touchpoint
            moving.style.left = event.changedTouches[0].clientX - moving.clientWidth/2;
            moving.style.top = event.changedTouches[0].clientY - moving.clientHeight/2;
        }
    }
}

function drop(event) {
    if (moving) {
        if (event.currentTarget.tagName !== 'HTML') {
            let target = null;
            if (event.clientX) {
                target = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
            } else {
                target = document.elementFromPoint(event.changedTouches[0].clientX, event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
            }

            target.appendChild(moving);
        }

        // reset our element
        moving.style.left = '';
        moving.style.top = '';
        moving.style.height = '';
        moving.style.width = '';
        moving.style.position = '';
        moving.style.zIndex = '';

        moving = null;
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #container > div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
  
    height: 10em;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  #movable-element {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: #00ff0033;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body onmouseup="drop(event)" ontouchend="drop(event)" onmousemove="move(event)" ontouchmove="move(event)">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left-parent" onmouseup="drop(event)" ontouchend="drop(event)">
        <div id="movable-element" onmousedown="pickup(event)" ontouchstart="pickup(event)"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-parent" onmouseup="drop(event)" ontouchend="drop(event)"></div>
</div>
</body>
```